# Adding Duplicate values to map, without external libraries

Tags: java, list, loops

I have a piece of code that loops through a list and builds up a map containing a date as a key and a value of `Pair<BigDecimal, Currency>>`. It loops though for every currency. It builds up the map correctly the first loop around but every loop after replaces the data due to sharing a date and therefore a key.

How could I change the logic below to handle building a map sharing a date to prevent different currency's amounts being added together?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [Multimap](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from the [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library.

It will be like a `Map<Date, List<Pair>>`.

Here is the description from the javadoc:

> A collection that maps keys to values, similar to Map, but in which each key may be associated with multiple values. You can visualize the contents of a multimap either as a map from keys to nonempty collections of values:

Comment: I cant use external libraries for this piece of code sadly, I've came across that before when searching for answers

Comment: Then @Ivan answer is what you need